# Selecting variables using SAS and R - all effects are significant even when shuffling the data

Tags: r, sas

Dear all: I need to test which effects I should include in my model for genetic evaluation of cows. I was using the following code in R:

model1 = lm(milk ~ factor(year) + factor(herd) + factor(season) + age + I(age^2), data=paula1)
anova(model1)

However, all my effects were highly significant `(< 2.2e-16 ***).` I treid using `step(model1)` to choose the best model, I tried to include other effects that I would never expect to be significant and they were. So I was thinking that I was doing something wrongly. Then I tried proc glm in SAS using the following code:

```
data paula1; set paula0;
proc glm;
class year herd season;
model milk= year herd season age age*age;
run;
```

And my results were very similar. I decided then to exclude some data and shuffle some variables and it is still signifficant. Now I have no doubts that my analysis are completely wrong, I just cant figure out what my mistake is. For some factors (e.g. herd I have more than 200 levels) and I have missing data as well (coded as NA in R and blank in SAS). The outputs look fine (sum of squares, degree of freedom, etc)
Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks. Paula

EDIT:
Unfortunaltely, I cannot share the dataset. However, it looks like:

```
ID year herd season Age    milk
1  2005  3    1      200     250
2  2005  2    2      NA      NA
3  2007  1    3      202     297
4  2006  2    NA     213     215
5  2008  3    2      215     222
6  2005  4    1      217     187
7  2004  5    3      225     165
8  2008  3    2      315     NA
9  2006  2    1      NA      146
```

I have around 30000 milk observations and the factors have: 4, 6, 2, 3, 3, 4 and 216 levels (there are other factors that I didnt show here). I have missing data in my file as well (NA).

One of the outputs from R:

```
model1 = lm(WWT~factor(A)+factor(B)+factor(C)+factor(D)+factor(E), data=dataID)                      
anova(modelWWT)
    Analysis of Variance Table

    Response: WWT
                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)
    factor(A)      3  83380   27793  924.340 < 2.2e-16 ***
    factor(B)     5 411082   82216 2734.337 < 2.2e-16 ***
    factor(C)      1  48071   48071 1598.727 < 2.2e-16 ***
    factor(D)     3 129684   43228 1437.672 < 2.2e-16 ***
    factor(E)       7   4816     688   22.879 < 2.2e-16 ***
    Residuals    28737 864067      30
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Could you add a small subset of your data to make things more reproducible? Besides, what do you mean by reshuffle variables?

Comment: Are you able to share the output from your `R` and `SAS` regressions? If not can you provide more details, sample size etc. As an aside, how are you going to interpret the estimates of a 200 level factor  - is it possible to collapse this?

Comment: a summary(model1) and the output of the anova table would be helpful.

Comment: I think this question is perhaps more suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions as it is about interpreting results.

Comment: How many observations do you have?  My guess is you have an overfitted model.

Comment: @LeoRJorge I edited my question. By shuffling my data I mean that I sorted some variables without expand the selection, which means that some effects shouldnt be significant.

Comment: @user20650 I just posted an R output not including the factor with many levels and still all the effects are higly significant.

Comment: @BondedDust, neither complete separation nor Hauck-Donner technically apply to linear models ...

Comment: Oh. Sorry for the noise. The confusion arose because "GLM" made me think this was a real glm.

Comment: The key here is how, precisely, you implemented your shuffling approach.  Sounds like you did something wrong there.  Can you show us code?

Comment: Hey @BenBolker, I did that in Excel. I just sorted the columns from the largest to the smallest value or vice versa. But I think this is not the problem, because sometimes I include some variables that I would never expect to be significant in the model and they are. For example, I created a new variable that is a combination of other 2 and all three of them were highly significant. As they explain the same effect, one of them should be excluded from the model and it wasnt. It looks really weird. I guees I will have to read more about that.